# Dynamic imports for SCSS / Compass?

Tags: compass-sass, sass

I have a SCSS project that builds on top of Foundation via Compass. It defines a set of sass variables, then defines a bunch of rules in terms of those variables: (my project has many more variable settings and import statements; this is simplified.)

**vars.scss**:

```
$foo = #fafafa
$bar = 14px;

// rules using $foo and $bar
@import '_rules';
```

I then use compass to compile **vars.scss**, and everything is great for that set of sass variables. However, I also want the ability to theme my app differently, and generate a different theme by defining a new set of variables which can override the original variables:

**vars.scss**:

```
$foo = #fafafa
$bar = 14px;

@import 'otherVars';

@import '_rules';
```

I can't edit the file manually when I have 70+ themes. (Having that many themes is necessary for the purposes of my app.) What I really want is to be able to do something like the following:

**vars.scss**:

```
$foo = #fafafa
$bar = 14px;

@import '{{otherVars}}';

@import '_rules';
```

And then I could call something like:

```
compass --otherVars themes/theme2
```

It would then be easy to whip out all the themes, because I could call `compass` once for each theme.

Does SCSS let you do this? I looked into it, and it doesn't look like it.

My current workaround is to split the original **vars.scss** into a prefix and suffix:

**_app_prefix.scss**:

```
$foo = #fafafa
$bar = 14px;
```

**_app_suffix.scss**:

```
@import '_rules';
```

**app.scss**:

```
@import '_app_prefix';
// no overrides by default
@import '_app_suffix';
```

And to override it for a specific theme, you'd make a file that looks like:

**theme2.scss**:

```
@import '_app_prefix';

// only override $foo - let the original value of $bar stand
$foo = #ebebeb;

@import '_app_suffix';
```

This works, but is sorta painful and introduces additional boilerplate.

My next problem is wanting to have additional `@import 'rules_foo'` statements, which also need to be constructed dynamically. So my overall fantasy would look like:

**vars.scss**:

```
$foo = #fafafa
$bar = 14px;

@import '{{otherVars}}';

@import '_rules';
{{ @import 'additional_rules' for additional_rules in rules }}
```

And I could call:

```
compass --otherVars themes/theme2 --rules "rules_1" "rules_2" "rules_3"
```

(Obviously this is somewhat handwavy but hopefully you get the idea.)

Is there a way to do this? Or am I going to have to resort to handlebars or some other templating language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always generate a temporary file that you send to compass. With python code:

```
import sys
with open('tmp.scss', 'w') as out:
    out.write(("""
$foo = #fafafa
$bar = 14px;

@import '%(pre-rules)s';

@import '_rules';
%(post-rules)s
    """ % {'pre-rules': sys.argv[1], 'post-rules': '\n'.join(["@import '%s';" % x for x in sys.argv[2:]])}).strip())
```

You'd call it like:

```
python stackoverflow.py themes/theme2 rules_1 rules_2 rules_3
```

And it creates/overwrites tmp.scss with the output you want.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't dynamically settable at build time, and it doesn't allow for multiple imports.

Comment: Hmm, yea ok, you're right... I changed my answer to more closely match your question. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, that approach is the one I'm currently taking (I'm using handlebars). I was hoping for something less hacky.

Answer (score 2):

For people who are using Grunt to compile their SCSS/SASS files, the solution was to add an extra parameter **loadPath** to "sass" task configuration as follows:

```
sass: {
  options: {
    loadPath: ['../src/css/themes/myTheme/'],
    style: 'nested',
    precision: 2
  },
```

And then in the /src/css/import.scss you can include those files from the theme as if they were in current directory:

```
@import "config";
```

The file was included from /src/css/themes/myTheme/config.scss.

NOTE: You can of course add a parameter to your Grunt task and have that theme name dynamic!